# A script to freely re-assign/remap/rebind the Stack Exchange hotkeys

Tags: support, script-request, keyboard-shortcuts

[the original  Stack Exchange announcement from 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site)

At least the hyperlink <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and code <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> shortcuts [go against the common web standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303411/339050) — in combination with the SE editor not behaving quite as expected with the (system-level) undo and redo functions I lose a bit of progress here and there when writing Q/A. Web applications may also clash with the browser hotkeys ([Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/keyboard_shortcuts/index.html), [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), [Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/shortcuts/)) — I'm sure many would like to remap at a larger scale without disabling the SE hotkeys entirely.

[image: the keyboard shortcut help screen]

Comment: Don't forget Ctrl + G that does not play well with Opera...